# Cannot install plugins using CLI

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I've been able to create a project using cordova and I can run the project both locally and on my phone. However, I cannot install plugins via the command line.

Phonegap -v : 3.1.0-0.15.0

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
[error] project directory could not be found

cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
[Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.]
```

Comment: realized I'd posted an incorrect command. just updated.

Comment: Are you in the directory you created with 'phonegap create'?  What version of phonegap are you using ('phonegap -v')?

Comment: yes. ive tried every directory i can think of. I added version above 3.1

Comment: How did you create your project? are all the folder structure in place?

Comment: ~/Documents/workspace/cordova-ios/bin/create ~/Documents/workspace/mydomain.dev/gap-ios com.mydomain.iphone Inviter

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are creating the project with the cordova node script, not the old create scripts that are under bin. Here's more on that: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_create_the_app

It should work with the git url, a relative filesystem path, and the plugin name:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Using the plugin name is the documented way to add features now: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_add_features

Comment: This gives the same error. Could this be caused by editing config.xml in Xcode? Ive been following out of date tutorials.

Comment: I just recreated a fresh directory with cordova and get the same problem. This is my create command - ~/Documents/workspace/cordova-ios/bin/create ~/Documents/workspace/mydomain.dev/gap-ios2 com.mydomain.iphone Inviter

Comment: Ah, that's the issue.  You want to run cordova create gap-ios2 com.mydomain.iphone Inviter

Comment: This works but this seems contrary to what the Phonegap documentation says ./path/to/cordova-ios/bin/create /path/to/my_new_project com.example.project_name ProjectName. Anyway it has solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@mooreds - thx, your answer finally pointed me in the right direction. Be warned I'm totally new to Java/Eclipse/Cordova but hoping this helps someone else - three days newbie research compressed into 10 actions that get me a runnable Android Cordova shell with a plugin installed on Windows:

```
1 Download and extract the ADT Bundle
2 Install Ant
3 Install Nodejs
4 CD D:\NpmModules
5 npm install cordova
6 add D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools;D:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\NpmModules\node_modules\.bin; to PATH then run:
7 - D:\NpmModules\node_modules\.bin\cordova create D:\Projects\HelloWorld4 com.mycompany.HelloWorld4 HelloWorld4
8 - CD D:\Projects\HelloWorld4
9 - D:\NpmModules\node_modules\.bin\cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
10 - D:\NpmModules\node_modules\.bin\cordova platform add android
```

Fire up a new workspace in Eclipse, import the two projects from D:\Projects\HelloWorld4 **WITHOUT** copying to the workspace and you're [hopefully] good to go.